# ERROR java.sql.SQLEception: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, database, sqlexception

I'm new to programming and I can't figure out how to fix this error: java.sql.SQLEception: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). The first JFrame runs and I get the message that it's connected to the database but then the error pops up and nothing is saved to my database. 
Here's my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SaveData extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection conn=null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;
ResultSet rs=null;

public SaveData() {
    initComponents();
}                 

private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
   conn=MySQLConnect.ConnectDB();
   String Sql="Select * from TripData";
   try{
       pst=conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
       pst.setString(1, txtTripDate.getText());
       pst.setString(2, txtStartDest.getText());
       pst.setString(3, txtEndDest.getText());
       pst.setString(4, txtMileage.getText());
       pst.setString(5, txtCost.getText());
       if(rs.next()){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Trip Saved");
           InfoSaved s=new InfoSaved();
           s.setVisible(true);
       }
       else{
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Information", 
"Please enter again", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

       }
   }catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);       }
}
```

Comment: The exception suggests the problem could be reproduced in a command line app., which means it has **nothing** to do with Swing. Tips: 1) Don't add irrelevant tags. 2) Debug the SQL part in a command line app. first.

Comment: If you want to save something to your database, a SELECT statement won't help you. Try INSERT.

Comment: You have no parameter markers (`?`) in the SQL, so what do you believe `setString(1, ...)` would do, and why? --- Also, `rs.next()` would fail with `NullPointerException` if code could get that far. --- Finally, what do you believe a `SELECT` SQL statement does, and why? *Hint:* It doesn't *save* to the database.

Comment: You're trying to set parameters to an SQL statement that has none, which, as you can see, doesn't work. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL string must contain a ?-placeholder for each parameter you want to set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this [it works if pst is a Statement]:

```
    private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        conn=MySQLConnect.ConnectDB();
        String Sql="Select * from TripData";
        try{
            pst = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            rs = pst.executeQuery(Sql); // Gets all the TripData rows
            rs.moveToInsertRow();       // Moves to "insert" row
            // Updates "insert" row columns
            rs.updateString("colum_name", txtTripDate.getText()); 
            rs.updateString("colum_name", txtStartDest.getText());
            rs.updateString("colum_name", txtEndDest.getText());
            rs.updateString("colum_name", txtMileage.getText());
            rs.updateString("colum_name", txtCost.getText());
            rs.insertRow(); // Inserts the "insert" row to your database
            if(rs.rowInserted()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Trip Saved");
                InfoSaved s=new InfoSaved();
                s.setVisible(true);
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Information", "Please enter again", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);       
        }
    }
```

EDITED:
[Code for pst as a PreparedStatement]
You have to change your query, you cannot INSERT (if this is what you want to do) via SELECT order.

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    conn=MySQLConnect.ConnectDB();
    String Sql="INSERT INTO TripData(COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_NAME) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    try{
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtTripDate.getText()); 
        pst.setString(2, txtStartDest.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txtEndDest.getText());
        pst.setString(4, txtMileage.getText());
        pst.setString(5, txtCost.getText());
        int affectedRows = pst.executeUpdate();
        if(affectedRows != 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Trip Saved");
            InfoSaved s=new InfoSaved();
            s.setVisible(true);
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Information", "Please enter again", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);       
    }
}
```

Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Thank you, I see some of the mistakes now. I tried that code and now I'm getting an error that says: java.lang.RuntimeException: incompatible source code - incompatible types: java.sql.Statement cannot be converted to java.sql.PreparedStatement.

Comment: Ups, I forgot you are using a Prepared Statement, sorry. This code is for Statement instances. I'm editing my answer.